# How to wrap and re-order elements inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I am trying to wrap some elements with jQuery in a li element. My problem is that I want to switch the order they will be inside the li. Right now is `li` start - `a` - `div` - `li` end, but I want `li` start - `div` - `a` - `li` end.

How can I do this? I tried everything but it didn't work. Here is my current code:

```js
$('a.top_link+div.sub').not(":first").each(function() {
  $(this).prev().andSelf().wrapAll('<li class="aaa">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="something.com" class="top_link">Something</a>
<div class="sub">Some other content..</div>
```

I want to wrap that and re-order the content to look like:

```html
<li class="aaa">
  <div class="sub">Some other content..</div>
  <a href="something.com" class="top_link">Something</a>
</li>
```

The elements above are more than one, only the content is different (part of a menu).

Comment: Please post relevant HTML too ..

Comment: add a fiddle is possible, will be easy to understand and rectify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('a.top_link+div.sub').each(function () {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev()).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<li class="aaa">');
});
```

For each `div.sub`, the above code does:

1. Move it to before the `<a>`
2. Add the `<a>` to the collection
3. Wrap both in an `<li>`

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/vjC3x/